# UI Tableview won't display or update search results in cells, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am an intermediate Swift developer and I am creating an app that involves using a search function to find an address and pinpoint said address on a map. I followed a tutorial on how to achieve this and everything is functional besides the search function itself. Whenever I type in the UIsearchbar my search results tableview controller is instantiated, however, the table view is blank and does not update as I type. An address API call should be present.

### Below is my code for the search table

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {
    
    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil
    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil
    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil
    @IBOutlet var searchTableView: UITableView!
    
}
extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.showsSearchResultsController = true
    }
    
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
              let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response
            else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

        
    
}
extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return matchingItems.count
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        return cell
    }
}
extension LocationSearchTable {
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
            handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(placemark: selectedItem)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

### This is my code for my initial view controller

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

protocol HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}
//for some reason my location delegate is not working (resolved)
class locationViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        return
        
        
    }
    
   
    
    var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil
    
    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var eventLocationMapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 10000
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
        
        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
        resultSearchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
       
            locationSearchTable.mapView = eventLocationMapView
       
        let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
                
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
                
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
        //this is the search bar
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
                
        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
                
        resultSearchController?.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
                
        definesPresentationContext = true
        
        locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
        //all of this is in regards to the search functionality
        
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.checkLocationAuthorization()
        self.checkLocationServices()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        //this pushes the user request. The issue was most likely in the switch statement
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        //solved it but we will probably have to go back to this
        
        self.centerViewOnUserLocation()
    }
        
    @IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        self.transitionBackToCreateEventVC()
        
    }
        

    func transitionBackToCreateEventVC (){
        let createEventViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "createEventVC")
        
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = createEventViewController
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        
        
    }
    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            eventLocationMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            //this function centers the map onto the location of the user
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func setUpLocationManager(){
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
    }
    func checkLocationServices(){
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            setUpLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            //show alert letting the user know they have to turn this on
        }
        
    }
    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            
            eventLocationMapView.showsUserLocation = true
            // We want the users location while the app is in use
            break
        case .denied:
            //show alert instructing how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return
        case .restricted:
            //show an alert
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            // we don't want this
            break
        @unknown default:
            return
            //I dont know if we need this code
        }
        
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
extension locationViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
              locationManager.requestLocation()
          }
      }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       
        if let location = locations.first {
            
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 0.05 , longitudinalMeters: 0.05)
                    eventLocationMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            
        }
        
    }
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print("error:: \(error)")
    }
}
extension locationViewController: HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        // clear existing pins
        eventLocationMapView.removeAnnotations(eventLocationMapView.annotations)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name
        if let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = "\(city) \(state)"
        }
        eventLocationMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: placemark.coordinate, span: span)
        eventLocationMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting the correct UITableView? I see that you have an IBOutlet`searchTableView`  and are calling `reloadData` on `tableView`....

Comment: You might be right. I just noticed that and called reloadData on my IBOutlet instead, however, the problem still persists. Do I need to do the same for all tableview mentions? Changing them to my IBOutlet?

Answer (score 0):

I think the you should make a property to hold the `MKLocalSearch` object in your `LocationSearchTable` class.

```swift
class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {
    private var search: MKLocalSearch?
    // ...
}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
              let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        // if there is an ongoing search, cancel it first.
        self.search?.cancel()

        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, error in
            guard let response = response
            else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        // make sure `search` is not released.
        self.search = search
    }

}
```

The problem of the original code is that, the `search` object, instance of `MKLocalSearch` class will be released when finishes executing `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` method, since there is no strong reference to it, and `start`'s callback will never be called, so your table view will never be reloaded.

What we do is just make a strong ref to it, and make sure it is not released before completion handler is called.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't seem to work. However, when I did add the code into the document I was given the error : Thread 1: "[<******.LocationSearchTable 0x7f82dc02a920> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchTableView.". I was able to resolve this thread by adding an IBOutlet for my tableview into the code. Even so, whenever I begin to search, the tableview stays dormant.